# Adding fallout-4 tags to fallout-3 and new vegas questions

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a lot of similar mechanics between the new fallout-4 and the previous fallout 3 and New Vegas games.

When the mechanics are the same between games:

Is it appropriate to tag newly asked fallout-4 questions with fallout 3 and fallout:nv?  For example:[How to hack terminals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243017/how-to-hack-terminals)

Further, should we add the fallout-4 tags to questions that pre-dated the game? For example: [How can I automate the hacking minigame?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124142/how-can-i-automate-the-hacking-minigame)

Comment: Honestly if the mechanics are the same and its already grouped up like the examples I do not see why not... But you could also add in Skyrim for lock picking to Fallout4 soooo maybe its better not too (they even use the same sound effects)

Comment: I am a little confused at how to interpret the question down votes here. Are they signalling that the people feel the answer is no? or that this is a bad meta question?

Comment: @ColinD - They mean that the person downvoting believes the answer is no.  It's an odd and confusing pattern that originated on Meta.SE and continues here.

Answer (score 8):

We should not be tagging alternate games under questions, even if the mechanic is the same, due to context.

For general housekeeping, it is better to have a fallout 4 lockpicking question that could be updated should extra relevant information be available.

Best example is in James suggestion. Under the argument of identical mechanic, you would also include Skyrim. But Skyrim does have differences, including the means in which you unlock lockpicks that do not break.

This mechanic is also in fallout, but the means to do so is completely different.

Comment: Even comparing Oblivion to Skyrim for example, the mechanics are similar but completely different at the same time. Best to keep the questions separate

Comment: In the same way, comparing fallout 3 to 4, the base mechanic is the same, but the secondary information that would make an answer a GOOD answer is unique to each game.